# With git, how do I save a topic branch after the parent remote branch was rebased?

Tags: git, git-rebase

I had a local topic branch based off a remote branch on the git repo:

```
1 - 2 - 4 - 5 - 9 - 11  master
      \
        3 - 6 - 8 - 12  remote branch
              \
                7 - 10  my topic
```

The remote branch was recently rebased off master:

```
1 - 2 - 4 - 5 - 9 - 11  master
                       \
            ?            3' - 6' - 8' - 12'  remote branch
              \
                7 - 10  my topic
```

I would like to rebase my topic branch off the head of the remote branch so that I can eventually merge my changes back into the remote. However, because the hash of the parent commit has changed, trying a simple

```
$ git rebase origin/remote_branch
```

results in a number of conflicts in files I've never touched.

Is there anything I can do to clean up these branches?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simply rebasing on `origin/remote_branch` is confusing for git because it tries to rebase outdated commits on the tip of remote_branch, which leads to duplicate commits and conflicts.

Instead you must plug off and on, to the new point commit related to the sixth one, using the `--onto` option

```
git rebase --onto <6'-SHA> <6-SHA> my-topic
```

`<6'-SHA>` and `<6-SHA>` are respectively the new and old ids of the commit where `my-topic` was created.

Comment: Perfect, did exactly what I needed. For anyone else stumbling across this, I was able to get the <6-SHA> by going back in the `git log` for my topic branch until I found the first commit from the parent branch. I then used the author, date, and commit message to search the log of origin/remote_branch for the new hash.